# "Nearly" in the phrase "nearly everyone"

Tags: grammaticality

Why is the adverb "nearly" grammatical in the statement "Nearly everyone has heard of George Washington" ?  The dictionary says "everyone" is a pronoun.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many quantifying determinatives (*three*, *a hundred*, *all*, *few*, *most*, and *many*, for instance) can stand on their own as “pronouns”, standing for the entire NP which they introduce in a full exposition:

> **Three** [<s>competitors</s>] finished the grueling course.
>   **Few** [<s>competitors</s>] remained standing after two hours.

Some of these quantifiers, however, cannot act this way, or cannot in all contexts—*no*, for instance:

> <sup>∗</sup>**No** [<s>competitors</s>] finished the grueling course.

Special forms of *no* have evolved which fuse *no* with another noun or pronoun to allow it to act the same way:

> **Nobody/no-one/none** finished the grueling course.

*Every* works the same way:

> *not* <sup>∗</sup>**Every** finished the course *but* **Everybody** finished the course.

Syntactically these are pronouns; but semantically they are still quantifiers, as is reflected in their pronunciations: the primary stress goes on the first element (note that *none* is a ‘worn-down’ form of ‘no-one’). Consequently, they are allowed to take the same preceding modifiers as their unmodified forms; and of course those modifiers are adverbs:

> **Almost no** competitors finished the grueling course. → **Almost none** finished.
>   **Nearly every** person has heard of George Washington. → **Almost everyone** has heard of George Washington.

Answer (score 2):

Great question.  I believe this is an example of an adverb interacting with a determiner:

http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~xtag/tech-report/node167.html

In your example, it makes most sense to me to parse "everyone" according to its etymological root "every one."  Then, per the link above, "nearly" is modifying the determiner "every."

You could also make the argument that "nearly" is modifying the entire noun phrase "everyone has heard of GW," but that parsing does seem semantically accurate to me, since we really do mean something approximately like "95% of all people have heard of GW" rather than "It's 95% true that everyone has heard of GW"

Answer (score 2):

**Everyone** is a pronoun, but is in a class of pronouns made up of

Adjective/Determiner + pronoun/noun

Everyone, everbody, everything

Anyone, anybody, anything

No one, nobody, nothing

Someone, somebody, something

The 'determiner/adjective' sense of these pronouns can be modified by certain adverbs as

nearly, almost, roughly, etc

IFF

the 'stand alone' determiner can:

Almost/nearly every...
Almost/nearly everyone...
(Compare: almost/nearly all...)

Almost/nearly any...
Almost/nearly anyone...

Almost/nearly no...
Almost/nearly nothing...

But

*Almost/nearly some...
*Almost/nearly someone...